# Magento PayPal Express checkout, we want to hide/Mask actual shipping address & make PayPal pass dummy shipping address for orders?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

We want to use Paypal Express checkout in magento but do not want to send the shipping address entered by user on our website to Paypal for verification due to privacy reasons.

We want to send dummy shipping address, which PayPal can accept for transactions to complete.

How do we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set 'NOSHIPPING=1' in your `SetExpressCheckout` API call and we won't ask for / return a shipping address to you whatsoever.
I'm not sure how you would configure that in Magento however.

I would not recommend sending dummy data whatsoever; that'll trigger all sorts of red flags and is simply not the right way to resolve the problem.